# After upgrading my android studio 2.2.2, when I run my app I get an error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

This is my **Gradle file**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anees.aneesdawran.osyar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: Please include the output of the gradle command. We need to know exactly why the compilation failed. If you are in Android Studio, then open the "Gradle Console" in the lower right corner.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal(alt+F12) and print

```
./gradlew clean build --stacktrace --info
```

this will show what's the problem